# VSCode 2022 won't let me make Xamarin Apps, select the "deploy" option for Android Game Deployment (Xamarin,.Net for android,MAUI)

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui, visual-studio-2022

VSCode 2022 won't let me select the "deploy" option,
won't let me create Xamarin Forms/Apps

I want to archive my game into an APK form
i am using Stride Game Engine and want to deploy(turn game files into a single apk)
Here's what i did so far:

opened the Project in explorer
opened the solution file
built the solution
Look for "Archive" in solution Explorer(Can't see the option) and see wether it let me tick the "Deploy" option in Configuration Manager.
Constant Checks on the Obj and bin folder for apk but nowhere to be found.

I have already installed Xamarin,.Net for android,Muai

I was trying to convert my game files (game that i made using stride Engine) to a single executable APK File. I can build Solution in Debug and Release Configuration but can't select the deploy beacuse it won't let me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is due to Visual Studio being unable to detect SDK's, Xamarin etc components because of improper installation.

Firstly uninstall VSC completly including the installer.
Download and install Latest VSC installer from its Official Website.

In installer instead of selecting and installing components individually
Select the ".NET Multi-Platform UI Development" workload in installer.
This will install all necessary SDK,s and tools.
**Note:Xamarin is treated as Optional in this package so don't forget to select "Xamarin" in checkbox.**

After installation in VSC open CMD as Administrator run `dotnet workload install android`

For installation of Android Workload for an older .NET SDK **(Optional)**

For example if you want to install .NET 6 SDK
go to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` and check if you already have .NET 6 installed.
If not then Run `winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.6` in CMD. After installation there would be a new folder in the same directory.

Temporarily move every folder except the .NET 6 folder to somewhere else then run `dotnet workload install android` in CMD as Administrator and after installation of workload move back the folders that you temporarily moved somewhere to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` Folder again.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

> there is no "Android" option thats why i am unable to make any apk. I
> can build Solution in Debug and Release Configuration but can't select
> the deploy beacuse it won't let me. I feel like there can be something
> that is missed during installation.

There is a similar thread: [Xamarin archives not appearing in VS - cannot build archives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/224540/xamarin-archives-not-appearing-in-vs-cannot-build).

You can first try the solution:

Try to repair the Android SDK by clicking menu:`Tools` ---> `Android` ----> `Android SDK Manager`

If the problem persists, please try to [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: there is no "Android" option thats why i am unable to make any apk.
I can build Solution in Debug and Release Configuration but can't select the deploy beacuse it won't let me.

I feel like there can be something that is missed during installation.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can try the solution mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: Stride Game engine uses Xamarin so its Xamarin.android app.

Comment: Hi @real_kira,  have you tried my solution mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I discovered various new errors.
1)I am unable to Create any Xamarin Forms/Android apps(System can not find  specified File. Exception from HRESULT0x80070002 )
2)There is no "Android" Options in Tools
3)Tried repair on vscc2020 even uninstall and reinstall
I know system is unable to detect the files but i dont know where the problem exactly is.
I will currently try to Remove everything workload and their folders completly from System and perform a full installation as you would do in a new PC.
if you have any thing that i am missing please let me know.

Comment: Yes, you can [perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs) and install the VS again.

Comment: problem is solved and i have added my my answer to the question.Thanks!

Comment: Congrats. Happy coding....   :)